# C++ CMD Screen toggle outptut in middle of screen?

Tags: c++, loops, cmd, sleep, cout

I was wondering if anyone could help me with my Death Predictor program? It would be greatly appreciated! I'm sorry if this is in the wrong section, I'm just wondering if it is possible?
Basically I want the cmd output screen to constantly be in the center, and not go on the bottom of the screen. it doesn't look very pretty. Thank you!
(DeathPredictorV1 code, if necessary)

```
//GOOOD LUCK
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <random>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
random_device rd;
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 20);

for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
cout << "\n";


for (double count = 0; count < 20; count++)
{

    int var = dis(gen);

    if (count < 20 )
    {
        Sleep(360);
        cout << "\n\t\t    It's your birthday! You turned: " << count << "\t" << var;

    }
    if (var == 18)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\tBang! You're dead!";
        cout << "\n\n     ";
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << "T   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "H   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "A   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "N   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "K   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "S   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "    "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "F   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "O   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "R   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "    "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "P   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "L   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "A   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "Y   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "I   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "N   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "G   "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "    "; Sleep(100);
        cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t  ";
        return 0;
    }


}

cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t  ";
}
```

Comment: The C++ Standard Library does not provide functionality to explicitly do this and the solution is platform specific. Unfortunately you did not include what platform you are targeting.

Comment: I use microsoft visual studio C++ 2013? I hope that's what your asking!